# Explanation in the proof of De Rham Theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds

With this Lemma in "Basic Algebraic Topology" by Shastri, the author want prove the De Rham Theorem.

[image]

Can anyone help me to prove the underline claim?

Comment: Note that $U_i = f^{-1}(i-1,i+1)\subseteq f^{-1}[i-1,i+1]$ and this last set is compact because $f$ is proper.

Comment: Yes, this is clear...my problem is how to prove that $U_i$ is finite union of convex subsets.

Comment: I see your concern now. It is not clear to me either. Try to see the proof of de Rham's theorem on Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (Th. 18.14). It is in the same spirit but it is a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

This claim is false.  For instance, consider the set$$V=(0,1/2)\cup(1/2,2/3)\cup(2/3,3/4)\cup\dots\subset\mathbb{R}.$$  The closure of $V$ is $[0,1]$ which is compact, but $V$ cannot be written as a finite union of convex open sets, since it has infinitely many connected components.  (In higher dimensions, you can similarly construct examples that are connected but whose higher homology groups are not finitely generated, so you cannot even use axiom (iii) to rescue the argument.)

To fix the proof, note that $f^{-1}([i-1/2,i+1/2])$ is compact and thus can be covered by finitely many open balls that are all contained in $U_i$.  The union of these open balls is then a set $U_i'$ which is a finite union of convex open sets, and you can replace $U_i$ with $U_i'$ for the rest of the proof.